# Confluent cloud elastic search sink connector

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-cloud

I want to connect the confluent cloud to elastic search (local environment). Is it possible to connect the local elasticsearch to confluent cloud kafka?.

Thanks,
Bala

Answer (score 0):

Yes; a local instance of Kafka Connect with the ElasticSearch sink connector can be installed and consume from Confluent Cloud (or any Kafka cluster)

A connector running in the cloud would be unlikely to connect/write to your local instance without port-forwarding from your router, thus why you should consume from a remote cluster and write to Elastic locally.